# Why would a stored procedure return a 0 and the selected id?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_myNewId]
    (@parentId BIGINT) 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Mapping] (ParentId)
    VALUES (@parentId)

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

This, when run on its own, returns the new *id* that has been assigned to the new row that's inserted with the *parent id*. However, when I do something like this:

```
DECLARE @NewId int
EXEC @NewId = create_myNewId @parentId = 33333
SELECT @NewId
```

When running this, the output window shows the result of the stored procedure, which returns an Id but `@NewId` always is 0. I fixed this by changing the stored procedure to use `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but I was wondering why `SELECT` didn't work in this case?

I have my suspicions that it's something around the 0 being the success status being returned first from the stored procedure rather than the result, but was curious why this doesn't then happen when called directly from the client.

Comment: SELECT is not RETURN, you want the latter.

Comment: You do *not* want `RETURN`, because `RETURN` can only return `INT` values (it's really only intended for a status code). If you use (or ever need) a `BIGINT` identity, you'll be severely out of luck. If you need the ID programmatically in T-SQL, consider using an output parameter. For client code, returning a result set is more convenient.

Comment: @AlexK. I think I understand that, though probably not the nuances of it, but why does SELECT then work fine when being called from another client like a web service?

Comment: Clients only eat the result sets and mostly ignore `RETURN` values, as you need special code to access that. T-SQL code on the other hand has no easy way of accessing the result set, save for `INSERT .. EXEC`, which is inconvenient and brittle. This tends to lead to competing approaches for returning the data depending on how you're more likely to use it. Client code can also use output parameters, but it's typically not as convenient as an `.ExecuteScalar()` call (or whatever the name of the "get the first column of the first row of the first result set" method is).

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thank you. This is more the answer I was looking for. I didn't really want people to get hung up on how the sproc should be written, but why RETURN works and SELECT doesn't when being called from within another sproc

Comment: If you want the full nitty gritty on how stored procedures can share data, I heartily recommend [what Erland Sommarskog has written on the matter](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html). Bottom line: you typically want to avoid having to do it at all, and stored procedures are usually written for optimal consumption by client code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No!  Write the procedure the right way:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_myNewId] (
    @parentId bigint,
    @outId bigint OUTPUT
) AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ids TABLE (id bigint);

    INSERT INTO [Mapping](ParentId)
        OUTPUT id INTO @ids
        VALUES (@parentId);

    SELECT @outId = id
    FROM @ids;
END;
```

Then call this as:

```
DECLARE @NewId int;
EXEC create_myNewId @parentId = 33333, @NewId OUTPUT;
SELECT @NewId;
```

The `OUTPUT` clause is the recommend way to get results from a data-modification clause.  The older methods using the `*_IDENTITY()` functions should be obsoleted.

Stored procedures do return values.  These are *integers* that are designed to return status information.  Other information should be returned via `OUTPUT` parameters.

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not deprecated, and works fine for a single row in a single table. A separate table variable does have some overhead, so replacing every use of it with an `OUTPUT` clause should not be done mindlessly.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful, and I will now write the sproc the right way. However, my main question has been a little lost in what the right way to write something, rather than why it happens

Comment: @JeroenMostert . . . I wrote "should be obsoleted", not "are deprecated".

Comment: @sr28 . . . Your stored procedure doesn't have a `return` statement, so why should it return anything but `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, I know you wrote that, and I understand that's your opinion. I have the opposite opinion, and I used the fact that the function is not deprecated to bolster that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - no, it didn't use the return statement, but then I don't need to use a return statement or output parameter to return a result set to my client backend. This sproc was working fine for my client backend, but not when called within another sproc. So my main question was why this was the case. Jeroen Mostert's comment below my question seems to be a little clearer on this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's design intent for stored procedures is that they always return an int to describe how successful the process undertaken by the procedure was. It's not intended to return a result data, and you're free to define the bits you want to return to describe succes, partial success etc. You could abuse it to return an integer result data (count query for example) if you wanted, but it's not the design intention

Executing a select query within a stored procedure creates a result set you can read on your client if the sproc is the kind that is intended to return data

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an OUTPUT parameter. Not only will it be 'easier' to use when calling the stored procedure, it will also be clearer to the person calling the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[create_myNewId] 
    (@parentId BIGINT,
     @myNewId  BIGINT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [Mapping] ([ParentId])
    VALUES (@parentId);

    SET @myNewId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END;
GO
```

You would then call your stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @myNewId BIGINT;

EXECUTE [dbo].[create_myNewId] @parentId = 0,               -- bigint
                               @myNewId = @myNewId OUTPUT;  -- bigint

SELECT  [This was just inserted] = @myNewId;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has 0 as return value from a stored procedure, check if the stored procedure executes from the right database and only one procedure exists within the given context. Output parameters wouldn't be of any use if you ever plan to access the DB with ORM and the procedure returns an object's property.